# One time RSA public key

Tags: security, encryption, rsa

I am new to encryption and I am trying to learn more about RSA and AES encryption and incorporate it to a project I am working on.

The situation is, I have a server running on local network lets call it a local server. The local server communicates with a remote API server via internet, the access to the API server routes is allowed only after user that is registered on the API server authenticates via Oauth2 which creates a session on the local server. There will only be only one user logged in to the local server at one time.

The goal I have set is to enable transfer of file from API Server to local server which the logged in user invokes. The current solution I have put together after reading through various online resources is as follows.

(Assume the user is logging in to the server and we have just validated his identity)
(1) local server creates a self-signed certificates
(2) sends the public key with the message digest to the API server
(3) API server validates the message, and creates AES key
(4)the AES key is encrypted using the public key from local server and sent back as response to local server with message digest
(5) the local server checks the message digest and uses the private key to decrypt the AES key.
(6) the AES key will be used to encrypt the file on API server and decrypt on local server.
(7) the public key is discarded on both local server and API server
(8) new public key is created on users next login.

I understand, using self-signed certificates creates a potential for Man in the middle attack. And it is generally not a good practice. However, on the opposite side it is difficult to generate certificates for local networks.

Apologize for the vague question, but I am trying to find what are the potential security problems with my solution please. I am keen to learn about the topic but I feel majority of the solutions I have found do not apply to my scenario.

So I would like to ask if such a protocol would be acceptable? 
What is the risk if the public key is used only for one request and than discard? Thank you for help.

Comment: Why can't you use TLS?

Comment: Thank you for the question, can you please expand on the context of what do you mean by TLS? Is it HTTPS? or is it securing socket communication with TLS?

Comment: Indeed Luke meat HTTPS, when done properly it will do all the things for you. All the same you can use self-signed https certificates and make them trusted (if you intend to use them anyway) without all the over-complicated hustle